# Create Schema in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am installing an application that requires me to set up a SQL Server DB with a schema.  According to the SSMS 2008 documentation, after creating the DB I can expand the DB in the tree then right click on Security and I should have an option New Schema but I only have New User, Database Role.. and Application Role..

I tried just doing it with T-SQL:
use myDB;
create schema mySchema authorization db_owner

The command succeeded so I would expect after this that if I create a table, the Schema drop down list should include mySchema as an option but it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh it. Highlight the Schemas folder and press F5.

Comment: there is no Schemas folder visible unless I'm looking in the wrong place

Comment: In SSMS 2008, look under `Databases/YourDatabase/Security/Schemas`.